# AVPlayerLayer slow instantiation

Tags: ios, xamarin, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayerlayer

Note : I accept any answer in Xamarin.iOS, Objective-C or Swift. If you need help reading Xamarin code I can clear that up for you, but it should be just fine considering the "complexity" of the code here.

I suspect my `AVPlayerLayer` to slow down my process.

I'm embedding a video/audio player in a controller of mine, using the following code in `ViewDidLoad` :

```
    void SetupLayer()
    {
        _layer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer(_player);
        _layer.Frame = PlayerViewContainer.Bounds;
        _layer.Player = _player;
        _layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
        _layer.VideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspect;

        //This is a UIView
        PlayerViewContainer.Layer.InsertSublayer(_layer, 0);
    }
```

As well as this, in the constructor of my own controller (containing the player) :

```
        public void SetUrls(string mediaUrl, string coverUrl = null)
        {
            CoverUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverUrl) ? string.Empty : coverUrl;
            MediaUrl = mediaUrl;

            AVUrlAsset asset = new AVUrlAsset(new NSUrl(MediaUrl));
            AVPlayerItem item = new AVPlayerItem(asset);

            _isVideo = item.Asset.Tracks.Length != 1;

            _player = new AVPlayer(item);
        }
```

This is the only relevant code called in `ViewDidLoad` and the constructor. The parts that are removed should be of no influence whatsoever (settings texts, loading assets and whatnot).

Now the issue I'm facing is that loading a "big" (By big, I don't mean more than a 4 hour video stream. Usually they are about 4 minutes long.
) file takes up a LOT of time. Up to 4 seconds. Between 0.5-1.5 in the constructor (`SetUrls` function), and between 1.5-2.5 in the `ViewDidLoad` (`SetupLayer` function).

I've timed it, and removing those methods drastically reduces the lag to something decent (but I obviously have no image or bad results).

I've compared to the native player, using the following code :

```
            _item = AVPlayerItem.FromUrl(url);
            _player = new AVPlayer(_item);

            _controller = new AVPlayerViewController();
            _controller.Player = _player;

            this.PresentViewController(_controller, true, _player.Play);
```

And it loads **instantly**. It's not even that the 4 seconds of loading is more evenly spread, it's that it takes less than 4 seconds altogether.

Considering it's probably loading during the animation, and that the screen is still black and not playing anything when the player is displayed, I'd say the native controller does the job in about 1-2 seconds (while half of it is probably during the animation).

Mine does everything before animating/showing anything. The only nice thing about that is that the video plays as soon as it can, no blackscreen. The downside is the horrible loading time of the controller.

Note : During that loading time, my UI is completely blocked. Which leads me to believe it's happening on the UI thread and that, maybe, it shouldn't.

## My questions are :

- Where are my bottlenecks here ? I'm obviously doing something wrong.
- What should I do differently? Maybe the way I'm loading the player in my own controller ?
- How can I load those components asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI thread? Will it be enough to reduce the loading time ? Or simply, is it even allowed to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Radin's answer helped me and I was having the same issue.  There is more information at this link - https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading/1387321-loadvaluesasynchronously

```
import UIKIT
import AVFoundation

typealias VideoDownloadResponse = (Bool, AVPlayerLayer?) -> Void

func loadVideoFromURL(urlString: String, onCompletion: @escaping VideoDownloadResponse) {

    if let url = URL(string: urlString) as URL? {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        // Load the asset's "playable" key
        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["playable"]) {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
            switch status {

            case .loaded:
                // Sucessfully loaded, continue processing
                // Build the player
                let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                //send it back to be shown in the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    onCompletion(true, layer)
                })

            case .failed:
                // Examine NSError pointer to determine failure
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    onCompletion(false, nil)
                })
            default:
                // Handle all other cases
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    onCompletion(false, nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your method to async and call `await asset.LoadValuesTaskAsync(new string[] { @"playable" });` Immediately after creating the asset. That will preload the video will not block the UI.

Comment: It didnt' change anything :(